# Assigning an element from a list to an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

this is my program

```
horas= str(raw_input())
horas=horas.split(' ',horas.count(' '))
print horas
array=[
    [0,0],
    [0,0]
]
i=0
for row in range(2):
    for column in range (2):
        array[row][column]=horas[i]
        i+=1
    i+=1
```

I successfully turned the given sting into a list but I'm trying to assign the object in horas[0] to array[0][0], horas[1] to array[0][1], etc. and it keeps showing me a 'list index out of range' error message. help

Comment: What do you think the value of `i` is when you encounter this error?

Comment: If you don't know, print i during the loop and see where it fails

Comment: thanks brian, solved it!! c:

Answer (score 2):

so the i+1 in the outer 'for'  was making the index go out of range sorry my bad lol

Answer (score 0):

If you were to have a function l2a (list to array position), that takes in a list position and the the dimensions of your array and gives back the x and y for that list position, you could write:

```
    for pos, value in enumerate(horas):
        x, y = l2a(pos, 2, 2)
        array[x][y] = value
```

Now you just have to write l2a and you are set for any array size. (hint, use the `//` and `%` operators.)